# Why does Tong uses Euclidean Gamma matrices in this step of deriving the Chiral Anomaly?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dirac-matrices, quantum-anomalies, clifford-algebra

In [David Tong's GT notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/gaugetheory.html) on page 137, he uses the trace identity for Euclidean gamma matrices given by
$$\text{Tr}(\gamma^5\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}\gamma^{\rho}\gamma^{\sigma})=4\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$$ Whereas for the regular Minkowski Gamma matrices satisfy
$$\text{Tr}(\gamma^5\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}\gamma^{\rho}\gamma^{\sigma})=4i\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$$
Why does he use the Euclidean one and how to justify it? I'm particularly confused since right after this he uses the identity
$$ \gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}D_{\mu}D_{\nu}=D^2-\frac{ie}{2}\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}F_{\mu \nu}$$ And in order to show this one I had to use the regular Clifford algebra $\{\gamma^{\mu},\gamma^{\nu}\}=2g^{\mu\nu}$ not the Euclidean one given by $\{\gamma^{\mu},\gamma^{\nu}\}=2\delta^{\mu\nu}$